# How to load an image from local storage into ByteData in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, file, local

How do I load an image from local storage in Flutter? I'm not talking about loading the image from asset. There is `rootBundle.load` to load an image into `byteData` from an asset and `NetworkAssetBundle` from an URI. I can't find one for loading from local storage. I tried to use `NetworkAssetBundle` by using `Uri.File` to convert a file to `uri` but it complains about not host found.

Comment: Use `File.readAsBytesSync()` which will get you a `Uint8List`. On that list use: `xxx.buffer.asByteData()`

Comment: There is no local storage in Flutter. What do you mean with local storage? Show the code what you are trying to do.

Comment: local storage means that file stored on the phone but not in asset. @Richard is correct. I was able to read `ByteData` by using `File.readAsBytesSync`.